# Merged wav file on Android App isn't playable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, wav, android-audiorecord

In my App I record Audio as Wav files and since there isn't a real pause function I have to merge the wav files to one.

Recording the part files works fine, but when I merge them the new file isn't playable.

I've used this piece of code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11452687/2043332

The merged file has the right file size but it isn't playable. When I disable the method to create the header, then the merged file contains only the audio of the first of the two audio files.

I guess something must be wrong in the header. Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: I am facing the same problem with the link you are using..Are you able to play merge file now??If so then please share the changes.Thanks..

Comment: No, it didn't came to a good result. In the end I've managed to merge mp3, which worked, but in the end was to time consuming. I don't merge files in my project now anyways.